# Select the number of English players from team which scored the most goals at home on a match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

TEAM

| ID | TEAM_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Arsenal |

MATCH

| ID | DATE | HOME_TEAM_ID | AWAY_TEAM_ID | HOME_SCORE | AWAY_SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-08-10 | 10 | 7 | 2 | 1 |

NATION

| ID | NATION_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Spain |

PLAYER

| ID | NAME | NATION_ID | TEAM_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | David de Gea | 1 | 10 |

GOAL

| GOAL_ID | MATCH_ID | PLAYER_ID | GOAL_ORDER | OWN_GOAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 106 | 1 | False |

I tried to calculate the number of English players from that team which scored the most goals at home, from the database above (SQL Server).

My query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(PLAYER.PLAYER_ID), MAX(HOME_SCORE)
FROM PLAYER 
JOIN NATION ON PLAYER.NATION_ID = NATION.NATION_ID
JOIN MATCH ON MATCH.HOME_TEAM_ID = PLAYER.TEAM_ID
WHERE NATION.NATION_NAME = 'England'
GROUP BY PLAYER.PLAYER_ID
ORDER BY MAX(MATCH.HOME_SCORE) DESC
```

It gives correct answer for the `max(home_score)`, but the count of English players in that team isn't correct.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including sample data and desired results. (Questions need to be stand alone, not require an external link to be complete).

Comment: Don't mix implicit join syntax `match, player` *(which became outdated nearly 30 years ago, with ANSI92)*, with explicit join syntax `player JOIN nation ON...`.  Instead, use the `JOIN` keyword between `match` and `player` and then specify the condition for that join. (At present you're joining every match to every player, whether that player was involved in that match or not.)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: [edit] any new info directly into your question.

Comment: do you really need your group by now since there are no non-aggregated columns in your select?  Also per your question: your not taking into account a "Home match" as far as I can tell.

Comment: I can highly recommend table aliases to avoid having to type the entire table name in every reference.

Comment: The count is off because in some situations a single player may score more than 1 goal. You would want to count(distinct Player.PlayerID)

Comment: Shouldn't the GOAL table be part of it to count the goals?

Comment: The MATCH table contains how many goals scored by home team in a match @LukStorms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first get the highest scoring team, then left-join `NATION` to `PLAYER`, then count the number of non-null `NATION_ID`.

You are also grouping by the wrong values

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
  p.TEAM_ID,
  NumPlayers = COUNT(*),
  NumEnglishPlayers = COUNT(n.NATION_ID),
  HighestScore = m.HOME_SCORE
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM MATCH m
    ORDER BY
      m.HOME_SCORE DESC
) m
JOIN PLAYER p ON m.HOME_TEAM_ID = p.TEAM_ID
LEFT JOIN NATION n ON p.NATION_ID = n.NATION_ID
    AND n.NATION_NAME = 'England'
GROUP BY
  m.HOME_TEAM_ID,
  m.HOME_SCORE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea5ea5fdf075a464f2b70afa4ef18fcf)

Comment: It doesn't give correct answer, it shows 95 NumPlayers and 95 NumEnglishPlayers

Comment: Seeing as you haven't supplied sample data I can't really test it, but I've switched the joins so it should work now

Comment: added sample data, and get these results:
9 456 95 6

Comment: OK have modified, I get `10,1,0,2` with yuor sample data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea5ea5fdf075a464f2b70afa4ef18fcf

Answer (score 0):

Just an untested notepad scribble.
Since I can't verify it without sample data.

```
SELECT TOP 1
  match.match_id
, match.home_score
, COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN player_nation.nation_name = 'England'
        THEN player.player_id
        END) AS EnglishPlayers
, COUNT(goal.goal_id) AS TotalGoals
FROM GOAL AS goal
JOIN PLAYER AS player 
  ON player.player_id = goal.player_id
JOIN MATCH AS match 
  ON match.match_id = goal.match_id
 AND match.home_team_id = player.team_id
LEFT JOIN NATION AS player_nation 
  ON player_nation.nation_id = player.nation_id
GROUP BY match.match_id
ORDER BY TotalGoals DESC
```